# Internet connection over WiFi stops until reboot

Tags: wireless, internet

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on a Toshiba Satellite L655.

After few days of installing, the internet connection started to stop occasionally after an hour or half hour and sometimes after few minutes and it only work again after rebooting then again after an hour or....etc it stops again.

The WiFi diagnostics:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10740773/

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) after such a forced disconnection and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Sorry for the delay, this time it took longer to disconnect. Anyway i updated the post with the link to the output

Comment: I suggest, you try the [proprietary Broadcom drivers](/q/55868/175814).